# error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, mysql-python, mysql

I get the following error when I try to install MySQL-python-1.2.3 under Python 2.6 in Fedora 14.

Fedora 14 comes with Python 2.7 by default and I am working in a project which runs in Python 2.6, So I am not in a position to update Python from 2.6 to 2.7.

```
_mysql.c:35:23: fatal error: my_config.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

The complete error message is as below

```
[root@localhost MySQL-python-1.2.2]# python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.6
copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6
creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb
creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb/constants
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.6
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,2,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.2 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/local/include/python2.6 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/_mysql.o -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fPIC -DUNIV_LINUX
_mysql.c:35:23: fatal error: my_config.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
[root@localhost MySQL-python-1.2.2]# python2.6 setup.py build
running build
running build_py
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,2,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.2 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/local/include/python2.6 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/_mysql.o -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fPIC -DUNIV_LINUX
_mysql.c:35:23: fatal error: my_config.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved this issue in the following way

1. Copy `MySQLdb` folder from site-packages directory of Python2.7 to Python2.6.
2. Also copy the following files from site-packages directory of Python2.7 to Python2.6.

   `_mysql.so`

   `_mysql_exceptions.py`

   `_mysql_exceptions.pyc`

   `_mysql_exceptions.pyo`

Now try the following

```
>>> import MySQLdb  
>>> MySQLdb.__version__  
'1.2.3'
```

Answer (score 39):

you need to install MySQL Development package

```
yum install mysql-devel
```

Comment: i can't find `mysql-devel` package in arch linux. what is the name of `mysql-devel` for arch?

Comment: Doing fast checking with google and according to this site https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/mysql-python/ it could be `libmariadbclient`. I never used arch-linux before

Answer (score 13):

Install python-devel. That should help